# Что возвращает единицу?

Tags: php, битрикс

Делал проверку на директории сайта, но если директория не совпадает, откуда-то возвращается единица.

```
<?
global $APPLICATION;
if($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."service/" ||
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."price/" ||
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."contacts/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."about/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."news/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."hot_deals/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."price/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."professional_tips/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."facts/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."sitemap/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."order_call/" || 
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false)==SITE_DIR."subscribe/"
)
{ 
} else {

if(empty($arResult))
    return " ";

$strReturn = '<nav>';

for($index = 0, $itemSize = count($arResult); $index < $itemSize; $index++)
{
    if($index > 0)
        $strReturn .= '&nbsp;>&nbsp;';

    $title = htmlspecialcharsex($arResult[$index]["TITLE"]);
    if($arResult[$index]["LINK"] <> "")
        $strReturn .= '<a href="'.$arResult[$index]["LINK"].'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    else
        $strReturn .= '<a href="'.$arResult[$index]["LINK"].'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
}

$strReturn .= '</nav>';
return $strReturn;
}
?>
```

Не подскажете, что возвращает единицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ужас-ужас-ужас. Попробуйте переписать первую часть по аналогии с этим:

```
$dir = explode('/', $APPLICATION->GetCurDir());
$dir = $dir[sizeof($dir)-2];
if($dir == 'service' || $dir == 'price'){ // и т.д., только осторожнее со вложенными директориями
    // действия
}
```

И добавьте `global $arResult;` . Походу, он пуст.

Comment: Все сделал как вы написали, единица все еще возвращается.

Comment: У вас в функции больше return'ов нету? Попробуйте каждый из return'ов по очереди заменять на `return 2;`. Который сработает - тот надо рассматривать подробнее.

Comment: Больше ретурнов нет. Я скопировал вам весь код.
Обом ретурнам добавил 2, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Значит, либо где-то раньше по коду из другой функции возвращается 1, либо идет обработка результата вашей функции, либо ваш код не является телом функции и тогда я не понимаю, при чем тут return.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, где-то в коде, у вас имеется строка наподобие ([Example #5 include() and the return() statement](http://php.net/include#example-130)
):

```
$bar = include 'noreturn.php';

echo $bar; // prints 1
```

> $bar is the value 1 because the include was successful. Notice the difference between the above examples. The first uses return() within the included file while the other does not. If the file can't be included, FALSE is returned and E_WARNING is issued.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте строку где у вас подключается этот компонент. Вероятно у вас там лишний echo, что-то типа такого:

```
echo $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(...
```

А должно быть так:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(...
```

Comment: вопрос был задан почти четыре года назад